# Is there a way to push changed to AWS Beanstalk instead of uploading an entire zip file on each deploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Im migrating a Play! application from Heroku to AWS Beanstalk. 
Heroku is really straight forward when it comes to deploying: Just push changes to a remote git repository on Heroku and the build occurs on the server side.

This is very convenient because it is not necessary to upload the whole project for each tiny change (Including all libraries!).

Basically for each change we are generating a huge 140 MB Docker zipped file that takes at least 10 minutes to upload.

Surely there must be a better way but a long search on Google only returned options to automize the file generation with scripts and alternatives like Jenkins but this does not solve the problem, it just automates the problem.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk supports Git based deployments similar to Heroku. However it looks like you have decided to go with Docker deployments and I believe that requires a full zip upload each time.

Comment: Yes, you can use eb codecommit for php or js projects. The piece of the puzzle Im missing is for a Play framework application that runs packaged. How would I go about using codecommit and have the application packaged on the eb instance? I have no problem at all to ditch Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got curious about this question too and had a conversation with an AWS specialist about different options here. Each option has it's downsides tho.

- The first option is to bake your application code, create an AMI out of it and carry out deployment using baked AMI. [More on that](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html)

  You have to test this approach first before adopting. The downside is that you would have to regularly maintain the AMI. You might also miss out critical patches from Beanstalk since AMI has been locked down

  A good [read](http://cloudacademy.com/blog/architecting-on-aws-dynamic-configuration-vs-master-amis/) on this topic
- The next approach would be to move out of Beanstalk and use CloudFormation where you can just upload your application folder to S3. Your CloudFormation template has to take care of spinning up all the resources required and using AWS::CloudFormation::Init and cfn-signals, it would be possible to install and setup software.Changes within the resource Metadata can be detected by making use of the proper CloudFormation signal and we can also run user-specified actions when a change is detected on the template specification.

  [(AWS::CloudFormation::Init)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html)

  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-helper-scripts-reference.html (set of helper scripts that can be used with CloudFormation)

Although these are not exactly a solution to what you asked for, they can be a good alternative. At least I made sure that you are not missing out any available options at Beanstalk.

Also one advice I got from them was to consider splitting up application into multiple components and sub-components. This would reduce your application size considerably.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks, Im aware of EB Codecommit, the problem is deploying the app after the code is pushed.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. AWS should really take a look at what Heroku does with build packs. It should not be difficult to implement and the benefits are huge.

Comment: Completely agree with you on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a [AWS CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/) repository, and use that as a `remote` for your local `git` repository. Next you can set up [AWS CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/) to build your application and deploy to Elastic Beanstalk whenever there is a new commit to the AWS CodeCommit repository.

This way you don't have to upload everything every time. Whenever you do `git push`, only the changed files are uploaded to the AWS CodeCommit repository, and then AWS CodePipeline takes care of building your application and deploying it to Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Long Answer: I ended up packaging the app with activator and not using Docker.

1. Crate a folder named "dist" in the root of the project.
2. Include a file named Procfile with the following line:

`web: ./bin/YOUR_APP_NAME -Dhttp.port=5000 -Dconfig.file=conf/application.conf`

Make sure to replace YOUR_APP_NAME with the name of your app as configured in build.sbt.

3. Package the Play app with the following command:

`activator clean dist`

That will generate a zip file inside target/universal/ folder in the project.

4. Deploy that zip file to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.